# Mocking Instance<T> with deep stubs

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want to mock a lazy injection with deep stubs using:

```java
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
Instance<MyClass> myClassInstance;
```

But `myClassInstance.get().myMethod()` results in a NullPointerException because `myClassInstance.get()` returns `null` instead of a mock.

Is this an unsupported feature or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using junit-jupiter 5.9.0 and mockito-junit-jupiter 4.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of [erasure of generic types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html). Mockito does not have access to the actual type returned by the `get()` method and in result `null` is returned. See [ReturnsDeepStubs class code in the Mockito GitHub repository](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/main/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/stubbing/defaultanswers/ReturnsDeepStubs.java#L63) for more details.

To work around that you should mock returning the stub from the `get()` method by hand in your test code or in a test setup method (`@BeforeEach`).

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to not have to use that workaround :)